# JavaScript not being called in inline event handler

Tags: javascript, forms

Here is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
    //Make sure DOM is ready before mucking around.
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        console.log('DOM is ready!');
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        //Each document field will have the following identifiers:
        //classCode, description, professor, file
        function uploadForm()
        {
            console.log('Creating FileReader object...');
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(evt)
            {
                console.log('Read complete.');
                console.log('Creating JSON object...')
                var documentData = 
                {
                    'classCode':$('#classCode').val(),
                    'professor':$('#professor').val(),
                    'description':$('#description').val(),
                    'file': 
                        {
                            'data': evt.target.result,
                            'metadata': document.getElementById('file').files[0]
                        },
                    'dateUploaded':new Date(),
                    'rating':0 
                };
                console.log(documentData);
                console.log('Adding document.');
                socket.emit('addDocument', documentData);
            };
            console.log('Reading as binary string...');
            reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('file').files[0]);
        };
    });
</script>
```

My HTML form:

```
<form onsubmit = 'uploadForm()'>
        <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Class code' id = 'classCode' required/>
        <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Document description' id = 'description' required/>
        <input type = 'text' placeholder = 'Professor' id = 'professor' required/>
        <input type = 'file' id = 'file' required/>
        <input type = 'submit' value = 'Upload!'/>
    </form>
```

This code was working before when I was calling `uploadForm()` via a `.click` event on the `<input type='submit'>` element, but that would ignore `<form>`'s required attribute check on the `<input>` elements. So now I am trying to call `uploadForm()` on the submit event of the `<form>`, but it is not running properly. `reader.onload` event should get called after `reader.readDataAsURL()` finishes, but this is not the case. I already tried jQuery's `.submit()` to no avail.

**EDIT:** Finally caught the error recording with my phone it. `Uncaught ReferenceError: uploadForm is not defined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `uploadForm` function is not in global scope, hence it cannot be found. Just define the function *outside* of the `document.ready` callback or make it global by assigning it to a property of the `window` object:

```
window.uploadForm = function() {
    // ...
};
```

Or a better way, since you are using jQuery, is to bind the event handler with jQuery instead of using inline event handlers:

```
$('#yourFormID').on('submit', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Onsubmit should be set to uploadForm() (that is, the expression you want evaluated), not just the name of the function you want executed.

Comment: Still does not work. I also tried onsubmit = 'uploadForm();', onsubmit = 'uploadForm()', onSubmit = 'uploadForm();' and onSubmit = 'uploadForm()'

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try some changes in your code.

Your `uploadForm()` function must have only

`reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('file').files[0]);`

All other things can be at `document.ready()`;

This way the reader object will be ready and when you call the function the `readAsDataURL` will trigger the onLoad event.

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Function "uploadForm" is invisible by DOM, because function "uploadForm" is defined in another function. In your code , another function means : `$(document).ready(function(){...})`.

In jQuery, you can bind event like this:

HTML:

```
<form id="myFormID">
    ....
</form>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    //Make sure DOM is ready before mucking around.
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        console.log('DOM is ready!');
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
        //Each document field will have the following identifiers:
        //classCode, description, professor, file
        function uploadForm()
        {
            //....
        };

        // ↓↓↓↓↓Bind events here↓↓↓↓↓
        $("#myFormID").submit(uploadForm);
    });
</script>
```