# In-line functions not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript not being called in inline event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035463/javascript-not-being-called-in-inline-event-handler)

Trying to build a javascript based like/dislike system using AJAX to perform the actions. The like and dislike functions are named "likeit" and "dislikeit".

HTML:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I like this." id="like" onclick="likeit('abc123');"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
<a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I didn't like this." id="dislike" onclick="dislikeit('abc123');"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    (function likeit(id) {
        $.post("likeDislike.php", {likeID:id}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            // Nothing to be displayed.
        });
    });
    (function dislikeit(id) {
    });
});
```

The error I'm getting in Google Chrome's Inspect Element is:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: likeit is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: dislikeit is not defined
```

Yet, they are defined right there.

Comment: So you should! Your function is buried under closures.

Answer (score 9):

Your `onclick=".."` stuff (which you shouldn't use anyway) can only access the global scope. Your functions are defined in the scope of the document.ready callback function.

The proper solution is registering your handlers using JavaScript instead of inline events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    function likeit(id) { ... }
    function dislikeit(id) { ... }

    var funcMap = {
        'like': likeit,
        'dislike': dislikeit
    };

    $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).data('action');
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var func = funcMap[action];
        if(func) {
            func.call(this, id);
        }
    })
});
```

Your HTML also needs some modifications:

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I like this." id="like" data-id="abc123" data-action="like"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
<a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I didn't like this." id="dislike" data-id="abc123" data-action="dislike"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></a>
```

Comment: So how can I get it to access the global scope?

Comment: @TechKat: Assign it to `window.whatever`. But it's actually a horrible solution. See my updated answer on how to do it properly.

Comment: Kiss the answer instead by marking it as the solution! :)

Comment: Oh, and +1 alone for calling out the use of `onclick`. That stuff just needs to be deprecated already.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//make sure jquery library loaded here

<a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I like this." id="like" onclick="likeit('abc123');"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
<a class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="I didn't like this." id="dislike" onclick="dislikeit('abc123');"><i class="icon-thumbs-down"></i></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function likeit(id){
$.post("likeDislike.php", {likeID:id}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
            // Nothing to be displayed.
        });

}
function dislikeit(id) {
    }
</script>
```