# Uncaught ReferenceError: <function> is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript. I'm making a js based calculator and whenever I click the 'calculate' button, I get two errors. I tried changing '$' to 'jQuery' in my script, but it didn't help. I tried changing the html in my button but didn't help. The js script has worked on other sites, so it's not that. It's the way I'm calling it or referencing it in my html.

Error 1:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: veganCalc is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick
```

Error 2:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

This is my JS code:

```
<script>
var formatNumber = function (x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
};

var kgToLb = function () {
  return v * 2.20462;
};

var lbToKg = function () {
  return v / 2.20462;
};

var gallonToLitre = function () {
  return v * 3.7854;
};

var litreToGallon = function () {
  return v / 3.7854;
};

var sqftToSqm = function () {
  return v * 0.0929;
};

var sqmToSqft = function () {
  return v / 0.0929;
};

function veganCalc () {
  var unit;
  var totalDays = 0;
  var years = $('#years').val();
  var month = $('#months').val();
  
  totalDays = (month) ? totalDays + month*30 : totalDays ;
  totalDays = (years) ? totalDays + years*365 : totalDays ;
  
  // Variables
  var indexes = {
    'gallons': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 1100,
        'metric': 4163.9
      },
      'selector': '.water',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'Gallons of water:',
        'metric': 'Litres of water:'
      }
    },
    'grains': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 40,
        'metric': 18.1
      },
      'selector': '.grain',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'lbs of Grain:',
        'metric': 'kg of Grain:'
      }
    },
    'forest': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 30,
        'metric': 2.8
      },
      'selector': '.forest',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'Sq.ft of Forest:',
        'metric': 'Sq.m of Forest:'
      }
    },
    'co2': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 20,
        'metric': 9.1
      },
      'selector': '.co2',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'lbs of Co2:',
        'metric': 'kg of Co2:'
      }
    },
    'animals': {
      'ipd': {
        'imperial': 1,
        'metric': 1
      },
      'selector': '.animals',
      'index': {
        'imperial': 'Animal Lives:',
        'metric': 'Animal Lives:'
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Functions
  var years = $('#years').val();
  var months = $('#months').val();
  var unit = $('#unit').val();
  
  //Prints
  $.map(indexes, function (v, i) {
    $(v.selector + ".index").html(v.index[unit]);
    $(v.selector + ".value").html(formatNumber( Math.round(v.ipd[unit] * totalDays) ) );
  });
  $('.intro.index').html("You have saved:");
};
```

Button HTML

```
<a href="#calculator"> 
<span class="button postfix calculator-btn" onclick="veganCalc()">Calculate</span></a>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-line functions not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110122/in-line-functions-not-defined)

Comment: if the javascript code is in it's own .js file, then you should not add the <script> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't replace all the $ with jQuery. Once I did that, everything worked.

Comment: so.. this is the conclusion after 8 hours? ;---;