# Why my function is not defined with Meteor?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have the following line in my site.html file.

```
 <input type="text" name="income" id="income" onkeydown="myFunction(this.value)">
```

I have a separate site.js file that looks like this:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
      function myFunction(val) {
        var income = document.getElementById("income").value;
      }
      var total = total + income;
    }

    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      Meteor.startup(function () {
        // code to run on server at startup
      });
    }
```

So essentially I need to obtain the value from the input field either with blur or as-typed (onkeydown) and add it to local variable "total" that is being displayed someplace else on the page. For some reason my function is not working when I type I get "myFunction is not defined" in the console. Where do I need to define it exactly (no JavaScript should be used in my .html file).

Comment: The function `myFunction` has to be declared outside of any other function (global scope), otherwise inline event handlers like `onkeydown="myFunction(this.value)"` can’t see that function. A better practice would be to bind the event handler using `addEventListener` (you said _“no JavaScript should be used in my .html file”_, but still use inline event listeners).

Comment: Here is your answer https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript not being called in inline event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035463/javascript-not-being-called-in-inline-event-handler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version that works with the blur event.
Markup:

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <input type="text" name="income" id="income">
  <h2>{{Total}}</h2>
</template>
```

And the javascript:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  // counter starts at 0
  Session.set('total', 0);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    Total: function() {
      return Session.get('total');
    },
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'blur #income': function (event, template) {
      // increment the counter when button is clicked
      Session.set('total', Session.get('total') + Number(event.target.value));
      event.target.value = '';
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using 'change #income' because input didn't work in my case (problems with number adding up). But yeah, this is what I was looking for. I guess it is a good idea to study a bit more of event references as they are very useful. Thanks again.